# Implementation of Sum in Ada

Tags: implementation, ada, factorial

1)

```
Sum := 0;
for J in 1 .. N loop
Sum := Sum + J;
end loop;
```

2)

```
Sum := ((N + 1) * N) / 2;
```

[image]

I've read that the first(left) solution is more "general" - applicable to a wide range of values ​​- than second(right) solution. What does "general" mean - can be computed without overflow?

Comment: Ada’s assignment operator is `:=` *without* a space in the middle. There’s something wrong with (1), `Sum` is overwritten every time, and it doesn’t give the correct value for any input. (2) accidentally gives the correct value for an input of 3. I thought you were just joking, but I see you’ve asked sensible questions before ...

Comment: Neither of those computes the factorial function, and neither is syntactically correct Ada.  (The `:=` operator is a single token, and you're missing a lot of semicolons.)

Comment: `Sum := 0;
for J in 1 .. N loop
Sum := Sum + J;
end loop;`

Oh, sorry! I've copied from the PDF. Therefore it was not correct.

Comment: The first equation from the looks of things is a summation, not a factorial, a factorial if I recall correctly is something like a 1*2*3*4...n type function.

Comment: I think that I've learned too much today. You are right! I've become so stupid :) ...

Comment: I edited the question to remove "factorial" from the question, but I don't have "mad editing skills yet" so if someone else wants to do it faster by all means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think “more general” must mean “can be computed without overflow for a larger range of numbers”.

The intermediate product in (2) will overflow at 2^31 - 1 (for a 32-bit `Integer` as you will get on most modern machines), which means that the largest legal result will be somewhat less than 2^30 - 1. (1) will let you continue almost as far again (if you can wait that long!)

This program explores the limits:

```
with Ada.Exceptions;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Summation is
   N : Integer := 1;
   Sum : Integer;
begin
   loop
      Put (Integer'Image (N) & " => ");
      Sum := ((N + 1) * N) / 2;
      Put_Line (Integer'Image (Sum));
      N := N + 1;
   end loop;
exception
   when E : others =>
      Put_Line (Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Message (E));
end Summation;
```

and if you compile with `gnatmake -gnato summation.adb` and run it it ends with

```
46337 =>  1073581953
46338 =>  1073628291
46339 =>  1073674630
46340 =>  1073720970
46341 => summation.adb:9 overflow check failed
```

If you leave out the `-gnato`, so that GNAT doesn’t do numeric overflow checks (a regrettable default, chosen as I remember for efficiency) this happens:

```
46337 =>  1073581953
46338 =>  1073628291
46339 =>  1073674630
46340 =>  1073720970
46341 => -1073716337
46342 => -1073669995
46343 => -1073623652
```

I suppose you could get the longer range by dividing whichever of `N` and `N + 1` was even (one clearly must be!) by 2 before doing the multiplication.

This isn’t really an Ada problem (though `-gnato` makes it easier to see when things go wrong than might happen with some other languages), and it’s certainly not a factorial! Is it possible to edit the title?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax aside (we're looking at this conceptually not syntatically),

Since we are really talking about summations here, I'll respond to that.

My first guess why the left is more general is possibly because most people forget that there is a shortcut to a summation of i from 1 to n. Since both equations are mathematically equivalent. Which one is the faster on your system?

One does the tedious task of adding each individual number from 1 to n.

If you take a look at the summation article on wikipedia, you will see that the summation from 1-100 requires 99 additions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Whereas the equation on the right (the shortcut) will only do a division and a multiplication and a single addition.

My second guess is perhaps in certain (maybe more) situations it would be faster to do n additions....that's a system dependent situation, as well as problem dependent, so I think that's less likely.

Could you give a reference as to this document, context would be really helpful.